Powershell Script to Extract Windows Product Key
I found this pair of functions to extract the Windows product key:
function Get-WindowsProductKey {

    function Get-OSDigitalID($Key) {

        $KeyOffset = 52 
        $isWin8 = [Int]($Key[66] / 6) -bAND 1
        $HF7 = 0xF7
        $Key[66] = ($Key[66] -bAND $HF7) -bOR (($isWin8 -bAND 2) * 4)
        $i = 24
        [String]$Chars = 'BCDFGHJKMPQRTVWXY2346789' 
        do {
            $Current = 0 
            $j = 14
            do {
                $Current = $Current * 256    
                $Current = $Key[$j + $KeyOffset] + $Current
                $Key[$j + $KeyOffset] = [math]::Floor([double]($Current / 24))
                $Current = $Current % 24
                $j = $j - 1 
            } while ($j -ge 0)
            $i = $i - 1
            $KeyOutput = $Chars.SubString($Current, 1) + $KeyOutput
            $Last = $Current
        } while ($i -ge 0)
        
        $KeyPart1 = $KeyOutput.SubString(1, $Last)
        $KeyPart2 = $KeyOutput.SubString(1, $KeyOutput.Length - 1)
        if ($Last -eq 0) {
            $KeyOutput = 'N' + $KeyPart2
        }
        else {
            $KeyOutput = $KeyPart2.Insert($KeyPart2.IndexOf($KeyPart1) + $KeyPart1.Length, 'N')
        }
        $a = $KeyOutput.SubString(0, 5)
        $b = $KeyOutput.SubString(5, 5)
        $c = $KeyOutput.SubString(10, 5)
        $d = $KeyOutput.SubString(15, 5)
        $e = $KeyOutput.SubString(20, 5)
        $KeyProduct = $a + '-' + $b + '-' + $c + '-' + $d + '-' + $e
        $KeyProduct 
    }
    
    $DigitalID = (Get-ItemPropertyValue 'HKLM:Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion' -Name 'DigitalProductId')
    $Name      = (Get-ItemPropertyValue 'HKLM:Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion' -Name 'ProductName')
    $Build     = (Get-ItemPropertyValue 'HKLM:Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion' -Name 'CurrentBuild')
    $Major     = (Get-ItemPropertyValue 'HKLM:Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion' -Name 'CurrentMajorVersionNumber')
    $Minor     = (Get-ItemPropertyValue 'HKLM:Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion' -Name 'CurrentMinorVersionNumber')
    $Owner     = (Get-ItemPropertyValue 'HKLM:Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion' -Name 'RegisteredOwner')
    $Install   = (Get-ItemPropertyValue 'HKLM:Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion' -Name 'InstallTime'); $Install = [datetime]::FromFileTime($Install)  
    $Type      = (Get-ItemPropertyValue 'HKLM:System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\' -Name 'PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE')
    if ($Type -eq 'x86') { $Type = '32-bit Operating System' } else { $Type = '64-bit Operating System' }
    $ProductID = (Get-ItemPropertyValue 'HKLM:Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion' -Name 'ProductId')
    $ProductKey = Get-OSDigitalID $DigitalID

    $Results = New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
        'OS Name'          = $Name + ' Build ' + $Build + '.' + $Major + '.' + $Minor
        'OS Type'          = $Type
        'Registered Owner' = $Owner
        'Install Date'     = $Install
        'Product ID'       = $ProductID
        'Product Key'      = $ProductKey
    }
    $Results
} 

Results generated by this function:
PS C:\Users\noira> get-windowsproductkey
OS Name          : Windows 10 Pro Build 22631.10.0
Product ID       : 00330-80000-00000-AA447
OS Type          : 64-bit Operating System
Install Date     : 10/5/2022 7:46:26 AM
Registered Owner : OwnerName@Domain.com
Product Key      : XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-3V66T

However, The one-line statement below yields a completely different result:
PS C:> (Get-CimInstance -Query "select * from SoftwareLicensingService").OA3xOriginalProductKey
XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-VT9QQ

The target system in question was originally shipped with an OEM version of Windows 10 Home. I then purchased and applied a Windows 10 Pro license. Finally, Windows was updated to Windows 11 Pro during the normal Windows update cycles.
Belarc Advisor indicates this is the definitive Windows Product Key:
XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-3V66T

So now I'm confused: Which of the objects referred to above, Get-WindowsProductKey OR the one-line statement is returning valid results?

OA3xOriginalProductKey will only return your OEM license keys. I am guessing you can confirm that the XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-3V66T is the Professional Retail key?

Belarc Advisor seems to think XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-3V66T is the real McCoy. I've used Belarc for years and am fairly confident with it. Your explanation makes sense, especially in consideration of the OA3xOriginalProductKey property request.  Thanks
